# How to implement a stateful dll in c++

Tags: c++, windows, dll, stateless, stateful

(sorry, not possible to post code)

When implementing a dll, there are advantages of being stateless. An example is video-analysis where the result depends on recent frames. The operations of the dll has a state (=recent frames). However, this state is memory-based so it can be owned by the caller and the dll remain stateless.

You cannot always make the dll stateless, however. Consider **a dll that is dependent on another third-party dll with state**. That state could be based on GPU, threads and communication resources. You do not want to expose the caller to this other third-party dll, so you need to (from within your dll) maintain state.

***How would this be achieved most elegantly and efficiently using c++ inside the dll?***

My current implementation has a class called `DllContext`. `DllContext` is instantiated only once, there will ever only be one object. There is a static pointer of type `DllContext*`, which will hold this object during its lifetime. Static here means scope: it is defined outside of any function body, not part of any class. It is reachable only from the minimal file that defines 3 dll entrypoints:

dll `init()`:
create the object using `new`

dll `deInit()`:
delete the object using `delete`

dll `doWork()`:
call the corresponding `doWork()` of the `DllContext` object

I dont like this solution. I would say it is **not a singleton solution** because the object is only reachable from the one single minimal file. It is still ugly however, any suggestions?

Comment: The typical C solution would be be to create an "initialization" function which returns a pointer to an [opaque data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type) which contains the state needed. This structure would then be passed around to the functions in the DLL. A C++ solution would be to have the "initialization" return an instance of a class instead, possibly using the [pimpl idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, This is the approach I have done with memory based state. It makes sense to me, the caller gets ownership (even if not permitted to modify the state himself). This seems to me dangerous when the state is non-memory. It implies ownership, which would not be true. Or?

Comment: What do you mean by "state is non-memory"? And if you design and implement it well, nothing stops you from using the "initialization" multiple times, unless the underlying "state" is for a non-shared resource (like e.g. graphics card or similar unique device). But even then you could implement your own internal sharing (with e.g. mutexes or atomic primitives or similar).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I think you answered your own question in the remark, I mention specifically GPU and networking in the question. However, there is a large chance I have misunderstood something fundamental, so please elaborate. In any event, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't have many options. Call `init` on first stateless call. Use a small wrapper static object, instead of bare `DllContext` pointer, to be able to call `deInit` in its destructor. Or don't even bother with `deInit`. [Why cleaning the house to be demolished?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120105-00/?p=8683) Unless there actually is a reason that is not "to prevent memory leaks".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Am I to understand it that you think the current solution would be acceptable, with the wrapper static object(that would indeed be an improvment, albeit small)? Regarding cleaning house. There could be reasons that are not memory (or threading) related. GPU and network resources come to mind.

Comment: @Stefan Would there be unwanted consequences that you know of if process ends without releasing those resources? If the answer is no then you should not bother with releasing them. But yes, your current solution is fine.

Comment: The Operating system in combination with the NVidia driver could probably free up the GPU resources in time... but less stable then doing it the recommended way, and not as fast. It seems better to free those resources, even if it meant by blocking calls, so that it is free for subsequent use in the same app... potentially by other modules.

Comment: Will hold with accepting and upvoting, in wait for someone to give a better answer. I really hope there is a better answer (I guess we both hope so :) ).